# how to extract .bin through shell, I downloaded the attachment in .zip file but gets converted to .bin file

Tags: android, shell

I downloaded the attachment in .zip file ( through gmail ) but when i checked through shell it gets converted to .bin file. I checked in /storage/downloads it is in .bin format. How to open it ? I want to extract my files. Can I change the extension ?

Answer (score 0):

first, check the file type with

file 
if the above reports that it is "Zip archive data",

then you can use unzip

Second, depends on the file command output